# Empty a dictionary subclass in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm using a django module that uses a class that inherits from dict.  Let's call it ExtendedDict. Suppose I'm given an instance, e_d, of the ExtendedDict class and I want to clear it out.  What's the most pythonic way to empty it?

This feels clunky:

```
for key in e_d: e_d.pop(key)
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Worse than clunky, that code doesn't work at all :-)  That code snippet attempts to mutate the dictionary while iterating over it.  If you can't use *clear*, then change the above to ``for key in e_d.keys():  del e_d[key]``

Comment: Good point.  That's what I get for typing off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your class inherits from `dict`, its instances should have a [clear()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear) method:

```
e_d.clear()
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use [`clear()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear) and do:

```
e_d.clear()
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries have a `clear` method. Can't you use that?